# How to tell if a map is a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone run me through the process of showing whether a map is a linear mapping or not. For an example I have:

$T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, T(x,y)=(x-y^2, 5x)$

I am aware that it must satisfy the conditions of:

1) $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

2) $f(kx)=kf(x)$

However I don't really understand how I apply the vector $(x-y^2, 5x)$ to this? Can someone run me through this example so that I can complete the rest of the questions.

Comment: The presence of the $y^2$ should be a strong indicator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, an element of your domain space is a tuple $(x,y)$

So, for part 1, you need to apply $T$ on sum of two elements of space$(\Bbb R^2)$

which gives $T((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))=T(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=(x_1+x_2-(y_1+y_2)^2,5(x_1+x_2))$

while $T(x_1,y_1)+T(x_2,y_2)=(x_1-y_1^2,5x_1)+(x_2-y_2^2,5x_2)=(x_1+x_2-y_1^2-y_2^2,5(x_1+x_2)) \neq T((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))$

Therefore, $T$ is not a linear map.

you might try to check whether it satisfies the second condition.

Comment: Thanks, I remember now :) I have most of them done although am struggling on one that says: $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, T(x,y)=e^x-\cos(\pi y)$, I have stated that it is not a linear map by using the condition (1) in my original post. Is this correct?

Comment: @KennySutherland:  yup

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, if the function has a quadratic component (i.e. $y^2$) then chances are it's not linear. This prompts us to look for a counter example.

Indeed, consider the vector $\mathbf{v} = (0, 1)$. We would expect
$$T(2\mathbf{v}) = 2T(\mathbf{v})$$
if $T$ were linear. However we instead find that
$$T(2\mathbf{v}) = (-4,0) \neq (-2,0) =2T(\mathbf{v})$$
Therefore $T$ is not a linear map.